# Dataservicecontext in WCF Service- insertion is slow savechanges()

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, dataservice

I have a list which has 1000 records `List<people> a = new List<people> {get; set;}`
And I have try to insert a each record at a time.

```
foreach( var d in a)
{
servicereferences.MiddleTier data = new servicereferences.MiddleTier();
data.id=a.id;
data.name=a.name;
data.AddObject("datas",data);
}
SaveChanges(data);
```

So by using Entity Framework -`DataServiceContext Addobject()` I've added a all data's into addobject method.

**Savechanges** insert the records a table into database.

It takes more time in **dataservicecontext**, likely it takes around 6 mins to insert the loop data into database.

Any suggestion's Please!! ( I have to separate into a batch as 1 request to save 100 or 200 records at a time)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

`Addobject()` maybe like this: `context.TableName.AddObject(TableEntityInstance);`

Means:

```
TableName: the name of the table in the database.
TableEntityInstance: an instance of the table entity class.
```

Here is a example:

```
public void UpdatePlayerScreen(byte[] imageBytes, string installationKey)
{
  var player = (from p in this.ObjectContext.Players where p.InstallationKey == installationKey select p).FirstOrDefault();

  var current = (from d in this.ObjectContext.Screenshots where d.PlayerID == player.ID select d).FirstOrDefault();

  if (current != null)
  {
    current.Screen = imageBytes;
    current.Refreshed = DateTime.Now;

    this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
  }
  else
  {
    Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot();

    screenshot.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    screenshot.Interval = 1000;
    screenshot.IsTurnedOn = true;
    screenshot.PlayerID = player.ID;
    screenshot.Refreshed = DateTime.Now;
    screenshot.Screen = imageBytes;

    this.ObjectContext.Screenshots.AddObject(screenshot);
    this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jiayao,

We are using a separate method to call the context and its as static and in same method and same class so, we are not using again calling the context.

Yes, we can call context also, even having a separate method in the same class,

But there is no difference in it. I am facing the same issue.